# Search filter nested array getting modified original array after Object.Assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

Trying to implement Search Filter on 2 level nested array based on the digits: if the digits/number match any sequence in my datastructure the results need to be exactly matched with searchcriteria:

My Data Structure: Original Array

```
TreeRange:
    {
        tree: '17200',
        treeRanges: [
          {
            id: 134055,
            strttreeNum: '5308550000000000000',
            endngtreeNum: '5308559999999999999',
            treeregistered [
              {
                id: 9,
                branch: '12345678989895559'
              },
              {
                id: 10,
                branch: '78912349494945449'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
               id: '23175',
               strttreeNum: '1234309999999999999',
               endngtreeNum: '3466309999999999999',
               treeregistered: [
                 {
                   id: 14,
                   branch: '5500001231234234'
                 },
                 {
                   id: 15,
                   branch: '5598761234444234' 
                 }
               ]
           }
        ]
    }
```

Current output: SearchFilterArray:

```
           {
               id: '23175',
               strttreeNum: '1234309999999999999',
               endngtreeNum: '3466309999999999999',
               treeregistered: [
                 {
                   id: 14,
                   branch: '5500001234444234'//only show this in search result
                 },
                 {
                   id: 15,
                   branch: '5598761230000234' //**Not suppose show this record**
                 }
               ]
           }
```

expected output: SearchFilterArray:

Search by SearchTerm: 4444

```
TreeRange: 
   {
        tree: '17200',
        treeRanges: [
          {
               id: '23175',
               strttreeNum: '1234309999999999999',
               endngtreeNum: '3466309999999999999',
               treeregistered: [
                 {
                   id: 15,
                   branch: '5598761234444234'
                 }
               ]
           }
        ]
    }
```

when i clear the search, the original nested treeregistered array need to be reset to Original Array shown above.
code:

```
{
if (!searchTerm || searchTerm === '') {
  return treeRange;
}
let filterArray = treeRange.map(aRanges => Object.assign({}, aRanges));
filterArray = filterArray.filter(
  treeRange1 =>
    treeRange1.tree.includes(searchTerm) ||
    treeRange1.treeRanges.some(
      treeinRange =>
        treeinRange.strttreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
        treeinRange.endngtreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
        treeinRange.treeregistered.some(
          treereg =>
            treereg.branch.includes(searchTerm)
        )
    ));

filterArray =  filterArray.map(filterTreeRange => {
  filterTreeRange.treeRanges = filterTreeRange.treeRanges.filter(filTreeRange =>
    filTreeRange.strttreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
    filTreeRange.endngtreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
    filterTreeRange.tree.includes(searchTerm) ||
    filTreeRange.treeregistered.some(
    treReg =>
      treReg.branch.includes(searchTerm)
    )
  );
  return filterTreeRange;
});
return filterArray;
```

}

its working when i search for treeRanges and returns filtered results but treeregistered array is not filtering as per searchTerm, i have added another filter below: the problem is my original treeregistered nested array getting modified when i do the search and when i clear the search i don't have original array available.
object.assign is working for treeRanges nested array but not for treeregistered nested array

```
filterArray =  filterArray.map(filterTreeRange => {
      filterTreeRange.treeRanges = filterTreeRange.treeRanges.filter(filTreeRange => {
          filTreeRange.treeregistered = filTreeRange.treeregistered.filter(
            treReg =>
              treReg.branch.includes(searchTerm) ||
              filTreeRange.strttreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
              filTreeRange.strttreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
              filterTreeRange.tree.includes(searchTerm))
        return filTreeRange;
      });
```

I have tried object methods, filters and maps. I know i need another map but i am not sure how to deepcopy, I am doing shallowcopy looks like minor thing is missing.

Comment: you said you do not have original array available. could you use Object.assign to get a deep copy of it first?

Comment: I am doing object.assign before the search filter let filterArray = treeRange.map(aRanges => Object.assign({}, aRanges));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in this lines:

```
filterTreeRange.treeRanges = filterTreeRange.treeRanges.filter(...);
```

and

```
filTreeRange.treeregistered = filTreeRange.treeregistered.filter(...);
```

you are mutating the `treeRanges` and `treeregistered` properties instead of returning a modified copy. do an Object.assign to override those properties while keeping the other ones intact instead.

notice that `Object.assign` only does a shallow copy, so you ended up modifying the original objects.

**here's a fully working demo:**

```js
const data = [{
  tree: "17200",
  treeRanges: [
    {
      id: 134055,
      strttreeNum: "5308550000000000000",
      endngtreeNum: "5308559999999999999",
      treeregistered: [
        {
          id: 9,
          branch: "12345678989895559"
        },
        {
          id: 10,
          branch: "78912349494945449"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "23175",
      strttreeNum: "1234309999999999999",
      endngtreeNum: "3466309999999999999",
      treeregistered: [
        {
          id: 14,
          branch: "5500001231234234"
        },
        {
          id: 15,
          branch: "5598761234444234"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

const treeRegisteredIncludes = searchTerm => treereg => treereg.branch.includes(searchTerm)
const treeRangesIncludes = searchTerm => treeinRange =>
    treeinRange.strttreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
    treeinRange.endngtreeNum.includes(searchTerm) ||
    treeinRange.treeregistered.some(treeRegisteredIncludes(searchTerm))
const itemIncludes = searchTerm => item => 
    item.tree.includes(searchTerm) ||
    item.treeRanges.some(treeRangesIncludes)

const filterByTerm = (treeRange, searchTerm) => !searchTerm ? treeRange :
    treeRange.filter(itemIncludes(searchTerm))
    .map(filterTreeRange =>
      Object.assign({}, filterTreeRange, {
        treeRanges: filterTreeRange.treeRanges
          .filter(treeRangesIncludes(searchTerm))
          .map(filTreeRange =>
            Object.assign({}, filTreeRange, {
              treeregistered: filTreeRange.treeregistered.filter(treeRegisteredIncludes(searchTerm))
            })
          )
      })
    );


console.log({
  filteredBySearchTerm: filterByTerm(data, "444"),
  original: data
});
```

Comment: treeRanges is not getting modified and it is resetting when i clear the searchTerm, but problem is with treeregistered array is not resetting  and object.assign is not working for inner nested treeregistered Array

Comment: Tried object.assign on parent array before applying this searchlogic:  let filterArray = treeRange.map(aRanges => Object.assign({}, aRanges)); but it is not working on child nested array treeregistered.

Comment: ok, I put together a working demo. the thumb rule is to avoid doing assignments on properties of subobjects, as that will indeed mutate the inner objects even if you do a shallow copy of the outside structures.

Comment: Thanks @Tiago Coelho, that worked like a charm, Understood the object Methods well in your explanation and implementation.